# Vtiger CRM Open Source version 7x (Meme Cache / Varnish?)

Tags: memcached, varnish, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am in the process of setting up Vtiger open source version 7x on my hosting account. Siteground allows Memcached and I am wondering if Vtiger supports this?

Additionally if anyone out there has implemented a Varnish server with Vtiger and if this is supported?

Answer (score 0):

I put this in the
Connectors.php  file

```
class Vtiger_Cache_Connector_Memcached {
         private $m;
         function __construct(){
                 $this->m = new Memcached();
                 $this->m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
         }

         function set($key, $value) {
                 $this->m->set("vtiger$key",$value);
         }
         function get($key) {
                 return $this->m->get("vtiger$key");
         }

     function flush(){
         return true;
     }
}
```

and in the Connector.php file I just commented out the memory cache and
added the memcached class

```
//                      $this->connection = new
Vtiger_Cache_Connector_Memory();
                         $this->connection = new
Vtiger_Cache_Connector_Memcached();
```